# How to get attribute values of the element that jquery.qtip2 selects

Tags: jquery, qtip2

My html document looks like this:

```
<span class="mytooltip" id="P21_12" waarde="56"><img...></span>
```

I want to pass the values of the `id` and `waarde` attributes to a function that retrieves the tooltip text. It works if I hard-code the values :

```
  $('.mytooltip').qtip({
    content: { text : get_tooltip_text("P21_12","56") }
});
```

But when I try to to access the attribute values the function is passed empty values.

```
  $('.mytooltip').qtip({
    content: { text : get_tooltip_text($(this).attr("id"),$(this).attr("waarde")) }
});
```

I must be doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that `this` is gone.. you can run an `each` loop and do it that way:

```
$('.mytooltip').each(function() {
    var id = this.id,
        attr = this.getAttribute("waarde"),
        text = get_tooltip_text(id, attr);

    $(this).qtip({
        content: { text : text }
    });
});
```